# Convert multiple word files into pdf files - software for Windows 10

Tags: pdf, document-converter, microsoft-word

I'd like to convert multiple word files into pdf files with a single operation and with a software (not online). Is it possible to do it in a simple way? I have Windows 10.

I tried CuteWriter, but for each file it needs to click on save button.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can actually do this with word.

Comment: So you need bulk word to pdf converter, right?

Answer (score 3):

[LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) can load Word documents and export them as PDF and it can be invoked on the command line:

```
soffice --convert-to pdf *.doc
```

or

```
soffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.doc
```

Providing soffice is on your path will merrily convert all of your .doc files in the current directory to pdf. *In my case soffice is located at `"c:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin"`*

- Free
- Offline
- Doesn't even need MS-Office installed
- Works from the command line, (or batch files),
- Cross platform, works on Windows, OS-X & Linux
- May have problems with complex documents, e.g. those that produce part of their content with VBA.

Testing on Windows 10 with LirbeOffice 5.2.6.2 shows that the second option above works fine with explicit filenames but not with wildcards so you may need to get a list of your doc files, `dir /b *.doc > temp.txt`, and then edit it into a batch file.

Your temp.txt should be loaded into the editor and should looks something like:

`Cv1.doc
cv2.doc
resignation.doc
letter_to_press.doc
Dont Know What.doc`

An you need to edit this so that it looks like:

`"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export Cv1.doc
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export cv2.doc
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export resignation.doc
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export letter_to_press.doc
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export "Dont Know What.doc"`

Which is quick and easy to do with the paste command, *(note that files with spaces in will need to be in quotes as shown)*, and save it as `convert.bat` in the same directory as the files then simply run `convert.bat` to convert all of your files.

Note that files with some "special" characters in the name will cause problems, spaces can be addressed by quoting the filename but others such as quotes, colons, semicolons, any of `&|!<>`, etc., are likely to cause problems and should probably be renamed.

Comment: Hello @Steve Barnes. Where is the command line? I tried in Command Prompt, but it does not work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try: `dir "c:\Program Files\Libre*"` in your command prompt and `dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Libre*"` to find our where your LibreOffice is installed, _don't forget the quotes_. Once you know where it is installed you should be able to use that _path_`\program\soffice.bin` as the command.

Comment: Hi @Steve Barnes. The program is in C:\Programmi\LibreOffice 5. I tried to write dir "C:\Programmi\LibreOffice 5*" after dir "c:\Program Files\Libre*", but the file is not found.

Comment: I tried also "c:\Programmi\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin". I get the error: impossible to run application. There is an internal error.

Comment: Can you run it by double clicking & by selecting start -> LibreOffice 5,2 -> LibreOffice? If  not there is a problem with your installation.

Comment: Yes, if I double click on LibreOffice 5.3, it works.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi If you right click on it and select properties you should get the path to it displayed, (if it contains any spaces you will need put it in quotes to use it on the command line.

Comment: Ok....I tried "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" and "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin". Both cases run the software normally (as double clicking on icon).

Comment: Good now try adding --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export _path_to_a_doc_file_

Comment: When I add (in the command line)  --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export path_to_a_doc_file after the command "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin", it shows an error message:  --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export path_to_a_doc is not recognised as internal or external command, executable program or a batch file.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Are you sure that you are adding it __on the same line__ and with the path to an actual doc file in place of _path_to_a_doc_ as I cannot think of any way you could get that error message other than typing on a fresh line.

Comment: Rather than using a long path _with spaces in_ from the command line change directory to the file location with the `cd` command then just use the filename __including the extenstion__.

Comment: I moved files, the new path is C:\Users\Raffaele2\Desktop\docs. I opened prompt command, I wrote cd desktop to go to the directory C:\Users\Raffaele2\Desktop>. Now what do I do? I wrote "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export docs (docs is the name of folder with doc files), but nothing happens

Comment: You need to name the individual __Files__ not a directory! @GennaroArguzzi

Comment: My initial question is how to convert many word files into pdf files with a SINGLE operation.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi My answer above explains that to do so you need to list the files with `dir /b *.doc > convert.bat` then edit `convert.bat` to insert the command _that is now hopefully working for you_ at the beginning of each line. Then run the batch file. The help for says you can use *.doc but my tests did not work with that.

Comment: The only thing that is unclear is "then edit convert.bat to insert the command that is now hopefully working for you at the beginning of each line. ". What does it mean? I wrote "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export convert.bat. This give me the file convert.pdf that contains the list of files. Instead the command "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.bin" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export docs does not work.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi example with fictitious filenames shown in revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFCreator](https://ninite.com/pdfcreator/) adds a "Convert with PDF Creator" option to Explorer's right-click menu. Ctrl+click or Shift+click to select multiple files, than right-click and select "Convert with PDFCreator" to convert them all to PDF.

[image: Select multiple PDF files, then right-click and Convert with PDFCreator]

You probably want to disable the "Save As" dialog after each document. To do this:

1. Open PDF Creator from the Start menu and change the default "Save" option for the "Default" profile from "Interactive" to "Automatic".
2. Uncheck "Open file after saving."
3. Specify the folder where these files should save. I put `<InputFilePath>` to save them in the same folder as the source files.

[image: Turn off interactive saving to batch convert faster]

Note: PDFForge (the makers of PDF Creator) have started pushing trial versions of PDF Architect (their paid software) with PDF Creator. To avoid this, install and update PDF Creator using [Ninite](https://www.howtogeek.com/201354/ninite-is-the-only-safe-place-to-get-windows-freeware/).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft included a free virtual printing service to create PDF versions of any Microsoft office document. Print as many as you like.

Comment: Hello @Numair Aidroos. The above service is useful only when You want to convert single files.

Comment: Try this service:. https://smallpdf.com/word-to-pdf

Comment: That allows to convert only a file at a time. In my question I specified no online tool.

Comment: How many files ate there?

Comment: How many files would to like to convert in one go?

Answer (score 0):

A quick shot at google with "batch convert word to pdf free" resulted in a number of links. One of the links had a compilation of five or six free programs, almost all of which had free/trial/paid versions. Of course, the free had limitations with respect to quantity of files to be converted and/or number of pages per file. It's not stated in the question, but any such limitation invalidates the free software option, in my opinion.

One that did not have this limitation is from WeenySoft : [Word to PDF Free Converter](http://www.weenysoft.com/free-word-to-pdf-converter.html) and allows for a batch process as well as storing/saving for future operations the settings used.

The specifications indicate it works on Windows 8 and might work fine on Windows 10, although not explicitly noted. Some of the converters I found don't work on .DOCX files, while this one supports them.

Nothing is said about ad-ware/spyware/malware being part of the download, but watch out for obscured check marks installing or changing your settings, common in free software packages.

[image: WeenySoft Converter]

Comment: Hi @fred_dot_u. I installed Free Word to PDF Converter, but the conversion is very horrible because the Pdf isn't equal to the word file. Often a word page became 2 pdf pages.

Comment: So much for a good looking free software package! No payload or hidden costs, but poor performance. Well, shucks. Try the google terms I suggested, maybe you'll get lucky in time.

Comment: If you know paid version of professional softwares, tell me them please.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are docx rather than doc you can use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) for bulk conversion, (not always 100% accurate on some complex documents). You will need a working latex installation, as mentioned on the site, for pdf generation.